# Adding 2 columns before the other columns in a csv file

Tags: java, jdbc, opencsv

I need to generate a csv file containing the ResultSet taken from database, from my java app. I have used the opencsv library. I am using a method "writeAll(ResultSet set,boolean flag)" and everything is fine. The ResultSet is written in the csv file. But now I have to add another 2 columns before the others.
These columns are not in the database. One of this columns will take the value of a database column and the other will contain static value.
Can someone tell me what to do please?

Comment: *"These [two additional] columns are not in the database. One of this columns will take the value of a database column"* - That makes no sense.

Comment: The simplest thing to do would be to change the database query that generates your ResultSet to contain the extra columns that your require

Comment: Well these columns are not database columns.These must be added by me.That's what "These two additional columns are not in the database" mean.

Comment: ... then what do you mean by "One of this columns will take the value of a database column" ...?

Comment: that one of the columns i have to add will have exact same values with a column in the database but this is just details.

Comment: Imagine a database with columns A,B,C,D..As far as i have gone i have written these 4 columns in the csv file.Now i must add another 2 columns E,F...The E column will have same vaules with  A column .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT a,b,c,d,a as e,'something' as f FROM mytable`

Comment: Question title says "before the other columns" but yeah, that's the idea.

Comment: Thank you very much SeverityOne.I didnt know you could place statics